# Why is my Python code unable to take input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

The code I've written for the 'Fashion' problem in SPOJ.com is unable to take in the following input correctly:

```
2
2
1 1
3 2
3
2 3 2
1 3 2
```

The code:

```
x = int(input())
spam = []

for i in range(x):
    y = int(input())
    for j in range(y):
        z = list(map(int, input().split()))
        if j == 0:
            z.insert(0,y)
        spam.extend(z)
```

The aim is to store all the input (apart from the first number) in the spam list, which will then be used to solve the problem. Can someone recommend the fix?

Comment: What does your current output look like?

Comment: There is no current output, only the EOF error

Comment: What does your input mean? In how far is your program "unable to take input correctly"? Does it throw an exception? Does it hang? Does it read only part of the input?

Comment: Also, how are you *running* your program? The problem might be that you aren't reading from standard output as well, but pass the input file's name as an argument instead.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking over [Fashion](https://www.spoj.com/problems/FASHION/) problem,  here is a way you can take the input and also submit successfully the problem:

```
t = int(input()) # number of  test cases 
# from the problem
# Each test case consists of 3 lines:

# The first line contains a single integer N (1 <= N <= 1000).
# The second line contains N integers separated by single spaces denoting the hotness levels of the men.
# The third line contains N integers separated by single spaces denoting the hotness levels of the women.

for _ in range(t):
    input() # first line contian the number of participants, we do not need
    men_data = sorted(map(int, input().split()))
    women_data = sorted(map(int, input().split()))

    print(sum(m*w for m, w in zip(men_data, women_data)))
```

---

so in your case, `y` is wrongly considered to be the number of the next lines, `y` is giving you the number of numbers from the next 2 lines in other words, is giving you the number of participants

Comment: If you're going to ignore the first line, there's no point calling `int` on it.

Comment: @chepner yes, thx!

Comment: But you *don't* want to ignore it; it supposed to be added to the output as well (that's the call to `insert` in the original post).

Comment: @chepner in the Fashion problem, the one that OP is trying to solve, it says clearly that the output represents only the sum

Comment: `For each test case output a single line containing a single integer denoting the sum of the hotness bonds for all pairs that MMDS has proposed.`

Answer (score 1):

Given that `spam` is going to be a flat list, you don't actually need all these nested loops. A single list comprehension will suffice.

```
from itertools import islice
import sys

spam = [int(x) for line in islice(sys.stdin, 1, None) for x in line.split()]
```

Though be aware, this does assume that *all* of standard input should be consumed. This isn't suitable, for example, if you only want to read the beginning of a redirected file, or are entering the data interactively from the terminal, since we aren't using the line counts to control when the loop stops.

Comment: So while running this on my computer, do I change the sys.stdin to input()? When I do, it returns spam as an empty list

Comment: You don't use `input` at all; `input` is a function that reads a line from standard input, strips the trailing newline, then returns the resulting  string. This answer iterates over `sys.stdin` directly.

Comment: That is, you could imagine `input = lambda x: sys.stdin.readline().rstrip("\n")`. (Ignoring the fact that `input` also prints its argument to standard output before reading a line. Too hard to fit in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

This code works. You should get `if` condition after `y` input.

```
x = int(input())    

spam = []
for i in range(x):
    y = int(input())
    if y == 0:
        z.insert(0,y)
        pass
    for j in range(y):
        z = list(map(int, input().split()))   
        spam.extend(z)

print(spam)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the output is:
[1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2]
I need the single line inputs (ignoring the 2 at the very top) to be included as well, i.e.
[(2),1,1,3,2,(3),2,3,2,1,3,2]
Could you please explain why the position of the if statement changes things, and the use of the pass statement?

Comment: "If" statement here behaves like "Assertion". Also, If you give "0" to for loop, it will do nothing, we want to prevent this. I put "pass" command to continue get inputs, but depends on your program requirements you can change it e.g. return "False"